# what is the voltage graph of the resistor that found in between two reversed ideal diodes in series?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics

[image: List item]

I find a small problem when I tried to illustrate the voltage graph of this circuit, I used multisim to help me but the result was confusing, sometime the graph is the same of the input voltage and sometime give me NULL voltage, I see the last result is more logical because D2 is blocked in positive alternance so no current goes in resistor and the same for negative alternance D1 is blocked. please could you confirm my point?

Comment: It's indeterminate - no wonder the simulator is having a hard time.

Comment: @KevinWhite The node potentials are indeterminate, but their difference, the voltage across the resistor, is zero.

Comment: @JohnDoty yes I think zero, according to ohm's law U=RI, as long as one of the diodes is blocked the potential between resistor equal 0V.

Comment: @JohnDoty - yes, but if any nodes are indeterminate it can result in the simulator being unable to solve the network. As Sphero suggests adding a ground will help. It may also be necessary to put a very large resistor (eg 1Gohm) from any indeterminate nodes to ground. That will be large enough to not significantly affect any results but allow the simulator to solve the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage across the resistor is zero with ideal diodes for any input voltage.

Maybe help the simulator out a bit by grounding the right hand side of the resistor- generally you need to ground at least one point for simulators to be happy.

With real diode models there will be a small voltage across the 1kΩ resistor due to diode reverse leakage. 1nA leakage will result in 1\$\mu\$V. The voltage will be more-or-less fixed for voltages greater than a few hundred mV, and will smoothly cross zero and change polarity as the input voltage changes polarity.

Comment: yes it works, thank you so much sir